# Publishing app with Ionic and Cordova on Xcode 7.2 issue

Tags: ios, xcode, ionic-framework, publish

I'm making the publishing of my iOS app that was made with Ionic and cordova.

Everything went well, except for the application loader

[image]

I have tried everything but I dont know what is this Toolchain tool.

If you have any info, it will be usefull. Thanks

Comment: Are you sure your Xcode isn't an old beta?

Comment: Looks like "El capitan" version of my iMac was an old version. I solved it opening the archieved file and writing an ID of Yosemite to the OS Machine build parameter and it worked. After publishing it, I updated my mac and crashed hahahaha. It wont boot now :(